# Error messege about identifiers in mupad procedures

Tags: matlab, mupad

I try to write functions in mupad but it seems I haven't understood how procedures and  identifiers work. I get every time the message "Error: Unexpected 'identifier'". First example: I tried changing the first row of a given matrix to [1 1 ... 1]. I wrote the following code:

```
shibutz:=proc(B)
begin
cons:=Dom::Matrix():
l:=max(cons::matdim(B));
for k from 1 to l do
B[1,k]:=1;
end_for
print(B);
end_proc
```

Second example: Another code which gets the same error is a procedure I wrote verifying goldbach theorm that every even number is sum of two prime numbers:

```
golbach:=proc(n)
begin
flag=bool(9<8);
theprimes:=select([$2..n-1],isprime);
for k from 1 to nops(theprimes) do
if(isprime(n-k)=TRUE) then
flag=bool(1>0);
end_if
end_for
return (flag);
end_proc
```

What am I doing wrong? which identifiers mupad didn't expect?

Comment: What have you tried in terms of debugging? I haven't used mupad myself, but when I tried your first piece of code (`shibutz`), I got an error in `line 8`, which is your `print` statement. I know that `print` itself should work, so I assume that something in the loop went wrong. Are the values for `cons` and `l` what you expect them to be?

Answer (score 0):

I just jorgot ; in the end of the loop (it had to be `end_for;`) and furthermore I forgot `:` before the `=` (so it had to be `:=` and not `=`). Sorry for dumb question.